# Create object from splitted strings

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help from you guys. I need to create a object from splitted string. Let me show you my code with explanation and hope you guys can help me.
So this is my current code

```
for(d in data){
    var item = d.split('_');
    console.log(item + "  " + data[d]);
    if(item[0] == 'partnerX'){
      //Rest of the code goes here
    }else if(item[0] == 'partnerY'){
      //Rest of the code goes here
    }
}
```

My `console.log(d + "  " + data[d])` inside for loop is

```
partnerX_row1_id      10101010
partnerX_row10_id     79899899
```

My `console.log(d.split('_') + data[d])` is

```
partnerX,row1,id      10101010
partnerX,row10,id     79899899
partnerX,row11,id     99999999
partnerX,row1,name    test13
partnerX,row10,name   test10
partnerX,row11,name   test1
partnerY,row1,id      10101010
partnerY,row10,id     79899899
partnerY,row11,id     99999999
partnerY,row1,name    test12
partnerY,row10,name   test77
partnerY,row11,name   test889
```

My problem is that end result should look like this but i just can't figure out how to properly loop through data, then push it to array and convert array to object or just directly create object, which would look like this one.

```
{
    "partnerx": {
        "partnerx_row1" : {
            "id": 3456788,
            "name": "creditor 1"
        },
        "partnerx_row10" : {
            "id": 79899899,
            "name": "test10"
        },
        "partnerx_row11" : {
            "id": 99999999,
            "name": "test1"
        }
    },
    "partnery": {
        "partnery_row1" : {
            "id": 10101010,
            "name": "test12"
        },
        "partnery_row10" : {
            "id": 79899899,
            "name": "test77"
        },
        "partnery_row11" : {
            "id": 99999999,
            "name": "test889"
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please share the value of `data` at the starting of code?

Comment: Updated. Basically the value before  split is just underscored string. Then i split underscored string in to array for easier manipulation

Comment: sorry some one edited my question and updated data is gone. i will rewrite it

Comment: I can't see any updations in your code. Actually, I was confused with this bit - How can `console.log(d.split('_') + data[d])` , ouput `partnerX,row1,id      10101010`. I suppose it should have been `partnerX,row1,id      partnerX_row1_id`. Am I missing something?

Comment: data[d] gives me a value, while d get's me a index of object. Mini update is added just to see how object looks like before split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the code. The result is stored in obj.

```
obj = {};
for(d in data) {
   var item = d.split('_');
   item[0] = item[0].toLowerCase();
   if (obj[item[0]] == undefined) {
       obj[item[0]] = {};
   }
   if (obj[item[0]][item[0] + "_" + item[1]] == undefined) {
       obj[item[0]][item[0] + "_" + item[1]] = {};
   }
   obj[item[0]][item[0] + "_" + item[1]][item[2]] = data[d];
}
```